# CheckBox in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have a listview in which there is a TextView and a checkbox. The ListView is used to populate data from a local SQLite database. If a button click is made, how is it possible to get the id of the ListView subitem, whose checkbox was ticked ?

The following is my main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_data"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:dividerHeight="0dip" >
</ListView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Things To Remember"
android:textSize="25sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My subitem.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:text="Title:"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/check"
android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:text="Test Data"
android:textSize="15sp" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:focusable="false"
></CheckBox>



</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is that, if i checked the checkboxes in each sub items and press a menu button, how is it possible to get the ids of each selected sub items in avariable.

Answer (score 0):

You use the

```
 SparseBooleanArray checks = yourlistView.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

to get all check positions, then you can get ids with

```
private final ArrayList<Long> getCheckedIds() {
    ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    SparseBooleanArray checks = yourlisView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    if (checks == null) {
        return ids;
    }
    for (int i = 0, count = checks.size(); i < count; i++) {
        int key = checks.keyAt(i);
        long id = yourlistview.getAdatper().getItemId(key);
        if (checks.get(key) && id >= 0) {
            ids.add(id);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.
But, when I write the second part of the code, it says to create a method "getCheckedIds()". 

[IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/9jhb3s.png[/IMG]
 [IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/232pds.png[/IMG]

Comment: Are you putting a method in another method?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I didn't see that. 
It was actually inside another function. But couldn't get it work. I added the whole code in the action event of a button. But not working

Comment: Did you set your list view are mutiple mode?        `yourlistView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29629/discussion-between-roshan-george-and-buptcoder)